# Resize UIView to hide the portion under the "cut line"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am designing an editable `UITableViewCell`<sup>*</sup>. In the normal state, my cell should look like the portion of this image above the red line.

[image: Table cell]

When users click `[Edit...]`, the controls letting the user change the settings will show up, and the text of the `[Edit...]` button will become `[Done]`. Clicking `[Done]` will hide the portion below the red line, and change the text on the button back to `[Edit...]`.

I am trying to achieve this effect by changing the height of the row in the delegate. When the cell is in edit mode, it's returning the full height; when the cell is not in edit mode, the height of the upper portion from the red line on is returned. Unfortunately, when I do that, the edit controls "slide up", obscuring the rest of the cell. I am fixing this by making these controls invisible in the edit mode, but I think there should be a better solution.

Are there settings that I could apply to the controls in order to let me cut off the bottom, clipping the content below the red line?

---

<sup>*</sup> I am using Interface Builder to design my cell, in case it matters.

Comment: is the cell you've designed changing size or are you simply adjusting the cell height programatically?  Could you perhaps modify the cell height and add your settings section as a subview which gets added to the cell when it enters editmode and is removed from the cell when it leaves edit mode?

Comment: @propstm I am adjusting the height programmatically in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. An idea with making a subview sounds intriguing - even if it does not do the trick all by itself, it would let me hide all controls at once by setting the "hidden" flag on the subview.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya You [hit the daily reputation cap from upvotes, it's 200 points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct).

Comment: So, i will not any points now? or will be credited tomorrow?

Comment: Ok so I remember why this scenario sounds familiar, I had a similar issue where it appeared that after cells are dequeued and then are reused the content appeared to have slid up, but it was because the cell was not clipping beyond bounds of the cell height as defined in heightForRowAtIndex.  A quick way to check would be to throw a label with just indexPath.Row in it to find out if you have the same issue.

Comment: I would try to subclass a `UITableView` and play a bit with `layoutSubviews` methods also. Your cell will layout the views based on a boolean value (it will track your editing mode). Hope that helps.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Any points that you get from votes until the end of the day today are gone. You'll get a fresh cap of 200 points tomorrow.

Comment: Are you using autolayout or springs and struts? If Springs and struts you jus need to give the view a flexible bottom margin so they don't move up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xib - just turn on the top strut

[image]

This is working for me. To make it smoothly expand and contract you'll need to use the trick of an empty `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```